# What happens if you follow the sun?

Tags: differential-geometry, applications

Travelling around for quite a while and sometimes, well, just following the sun, today the question occurred to me: What happens if you really do this?

So let's say some point is moving along the earth's surface, with constant velocity, at each time heading in that direction in which the sun appears to it (as long as the sun is visible to it; let's say it is motionless from local sunset to local sunrise, and also when locally the sun is in zenith). I am fine with the idealisation that the earth is a sphere, but if possible I would like to have the earth's orbit as an ellipse, and the axis tilt in consideration. (Relativistic effects on the other hand as well as axial precession, nutation and the like do not have to be considered.) The answer obviously would have as parameters the chosen velocity and (the latitude of) the starting point. Graphics would probably be nice.

Comment: Do you stop at night?

Comment: A rough outline: for each point on the earth's surface, find $\vec{F}(t)$, a vector in the direction a pole's shadow would be cast at time $t$ (in universal time). This would be the kind of thing that a sundial maker would use. Then you are asking to solve the differential equation $\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}=-v\frac{\vec{F}(t)}{\left\|\vec{F}(t)\right\|}$ where $v$ is the traveler's constant speed.

Comment: Say you are in the Northern hemisphere. Then in the morning you go southeast, at noon south, and in the afternoon southwest. So your trajectory would look a little like a ball bouncing towards the equator with gravity pointing westward.

Comment: alex.jordan: Yes, stop from local sunset to sunrise. @Rahul: Surely the equator is an attractor, but I wondered if according to chosen speed you end up bouncing around it periodically, or what? Also, the axis tilt makes this more complicated.

Comment: Usually Iwould also expect that you would go a little bit west every day. In the morning, you go east towards the sun and thus reach the point where the sun is directly above you some seconds before Mid-day. Then for the rest of the day you would go east. So every day you got a bit more to the west then to the east.

Comment: If your speed is sufficiently large you will end up at some point on the earth, where the sun is pependicular to your position, i.e. in zenith. From then on, you will be moving as the sun moves, i.e. your path $c(t)$ on earth's surface is the point at which sun is in zenith at $t$. I am sure this has an astronomical name, but i can't find it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsolar_point I guess. We can agree that this happens eventually as soon as you are as fast as or faster than the movement of this point (which should be a little higher than earth's rotation speed due to axis tilt). I would still like to see what patterns emerge before reaching this stable state, and what happens exactly if you travel slower (which I, for my part, do).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are going in the direction of the sun, you won't remain on the same latitude (due the tilt of the earth). You keep on going down (if you are near the North Pole) or up (if you are near the South Pole) till you reach a latitude where you would go down and then up equally; thus reaching back to the starting latitude. This latitude could be anywhere on the earth and would vary upon the date of the year. As the date changes, so will the latitude where you can possibly return to.

As for your speed, the perfect speed required would vary depending on your place on the earth. If you travel at a constant velocity, you will probably either not be able to catch up with the sun, or find it overhead and wait (or reach the next night, in rare circumstances, wherein you'll have to wait till the sun rises for the place on the earth).

I'm not 100% sure though.